# How to preserve a span width using 'inline-block'

Tags: css

I would like to apply transformations on specific letters in a word.

In order to make my css `transform` property working, I'm forced to set `display:inline-block;` to my spans elements.

Unfortunately, as soon as I change from inline to inline-block, the width between my letters is changing.

[image]

Here's a code pen to illustrate my issue : https://codepen.io/michaelgrc/pen/XWNpaJd

I tried to play width the parent font-size to 0, with the space-wrap property, width the letter-spacing property, it doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea ?
Thank you very much

**EDIT** : the font-kerning property only allows me to have my first word like the second. But I want the opposite : I want my second word to look like the first.

Comment: it's about the interaction between the A and V

Comment: It's called font kerning. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning). If you set it to "none" for class `basic-behavior` it all works as expected.

Comment: Hi @Gerard, thanks for your answer but unfortunately I don't want my first sentence to look like the second one. I want the opposite. I want my second sentence to look like the first one. But your css property doesn't seems to do the trick...

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate? The linked questions don't solve the problem at hand (which is to keep kerning between adjacent text wrapped with an `inline-block` container). @Michaël I would recommend voting to reopen this issue (next to the follow link).